# How to format the docstring for inherited methods in python?

Tags: python, string, inheritance, format, docstring

I have the following objects, in `cars.py`

```
import abc

class Car(abc.ABC):

  def drive(self):
    """This is the docstring for how to drive a {0}."""
    pass

class Van(Car):

  def shut_sliding_door(self):
    pass

class Hybrid(Car):

  def plug_in(self):
    pass

Van.drive.__doc__ = Car.drive.__doc__.format('van')
Hybrid.drive.__doc__ = Car.drive.__doc__.format('hybrid')
```

However, the docstring for `Hybrid.drive` is formatted with the `"van"` string rather than the `"hybrid"` string.

```
import cars as cars

cars.Hybrid.drive.__doc__
> "This is the docstring for how to drive a van."

cars.Van.drive.__doc__
> "This is the docstring for how to drive a van."
```

It appears that the line `Van.drive.__doc__ = Car.drive.__doc__.format('van')` is changing the string `Car.drive.__doc__.format('van')`. This is confirmed with,

```
cars.Car.drive.__doc__
> "This is the docstring for how to drive a van."
```

How do I format the string for `Hybrid.drive.__doc__` so that it is `"This is the docstring for how to drive a hybrid"`?

Edit:

Although overriding the `drive` method in the children classes can work, what if `drive` is a long method and all I want to change about it in the children classes are the docstring?

Comment: I've commented on what the answer is missing. I appreciate your help but I don't consider this question "answered".

Answer (score 0):

That is because you did not override the method in the children class. So at the very first, if you call `Hybrid.drive` that is the exact same method as `Car.drive`, there is only one method existing no matter the class you access it from

If you override them, you'll get different method, each one has its own and so its own docstring

```
class Car(abc.ABC):
    def drive(self):
        """This is the docstring for how to drive a {0}."""
        pass

class Van(Car):
    def shut_sliding_door(self):
        pass
    def drive(self):
        pass

class Hybrid(Car):
    def plug_in(self):
        pass
    def drive(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Van.drive.__doc__    = Car.drive.__doc__.format('van')
    Hybrid.drive.__doc__ = Car.drive.__doc__.format('hybrid')

    print(Van.drive.__doc__)     # This is the docstring for how to drive a van.
    print(Hybrid.drive.__doc__)  # This is the docstring for how to drive a hybrid.
    print(Car.drive.__doc__)     # This is the docstring for how to drive a {0}.
```

Comment: Although this works here, what if drive is a long method and all I want to change about it in the children classes are the docstring?

Comment: @NewNameStat Think about the sense, why would you provide different docstring for the **exact** same method ? If you don't override the method, the docstring should be '... for how to drive a car' and no precise what kind of vehicule because the method is built for a type of hehicule

Comment: I see what you're saying but let's just say that I do want to provide a different docstring for the exact same method. Is it possible without overriding the method?

Comment: @NewNameStat I don't think so, I have on further info about that